# How do I properly use getline() to turn strings to ints?

Tags: c++, getline

I have an input txt file that looks like so:

3 2

ATCGATTGA

GACTATACG

I'm using fstream, and creating it as a string.  I'm then able to turn 3 and 2 into their own separate ints, but want to also turn the next two lines into ints as well.  I'm trying to use getline() because I am told that would be the most efficient, but can't figure out how to create the lower two as their own ints.  Any help on how to get that to work?

Comment: Wait, you want to convert `ATCGATTGA` to an integer? How is that possible?

Comment: You use `std::istringstream` or `std::stoi` to achieve that.

Comment: The way I got the first two was string.at(0) and string.at(2), but it doesn't seem like that would be viable for following lines.  The txt file will always have the same format, but the second number will always be the amount of following lines below.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yea, I'm thinking A=0 T=1 C=2 G=3 or something similar so I could convert to an int.

Comment: @Chief So these are numbers in base 4? Numbers in base 10? What would be the value of `AT`, for example, and would it be the same as the number for `T`? Are they the same? `A` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

getline isn't going to convert a string to an int. Just not what it's intended to do.

If you want to convert `ATCGATTGA` to an int, the obvious approach would be to treat the input as base 4. If memory serves, the "order" is usually given as A-T-C-G. Assuming that's correct, you'd treat them as A=0, T=1, C=2, G=3, and convert the sequences accordingly (but note that for our purposes, the order you choose doesn't really matter, as long as you use the same order for both encoding and decoding).

```
int cvt_amino(std::string const &amino) { 
    int result = 0;

    for (char c : amino) { 
        result *= 4;
        switch(c) { 
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                result += 0;
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                 result += 1;
                 break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                 result += 2;
                 break;
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                 result += 3;
                 break;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("Error: bad argument");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result is a unique number for each sequence (up to the maximum that will fit in an int). Modulo bugs (I haven't tested this code) you should be able to convert a result back to the original sequence that generated it.

That does assume that the length of each original sequence is known/fixed. If lengths might vary, you won't know the number of leading 'A's to include. In such a case, you probably want to switch to base 5, and change the mapping to A=1, T=2, C=3, G=4. This removes the ambiguity with respect to variable-length inputs (but reduces the maximum length that will fit in a given variable size).

As far as reading data from the file goes, it seems pretty trivial, at least assuming we know the input format. For the format you've given above, you might use something like this:

```
int a, b;

your_file >> a >> b; // read the 3 and 2

// We'll assume an arbitrary number of space-separated sequences after that:
std::string input;
std:vector<int> values;

while (your_file >> input)
    values.push_back(cvt_amino(input));
```

Comment: the problem is then how to I pick out the lines from the main string to then convert to the ints?

Comment: @Chief: Edited to include at least some idea of how to handle that.

Comment: This works as long as the input has a fixed length that you can consider during "reserialisation". Otherwise, if you have leading `A`s, length is lost; you can't recreate the original string from your integer. As such, this scheme is not actually "unique for each sequence".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Good point. I did assume that based on the inputs in the question being the same length, but probably should have noted the assumption. If that's not correct, change to base 5, with A=1, TC=2, C=3, G =4 instead.

Comment: Yep, I'd go with that. Slightly more "wasteful" in general, but at least it's guaranteed unambiguous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've edited to include both possibilities.

Comment: @JerryCoffin could you explain the reading from file portion?

Comment: @Chief: It reads a white-space delimited string, then uses the previous function to convert that to an `int`. When reading fails, the `while (your_file >> input)` will evaluate to `false`, so reading will stop.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ok that makes sense.  What exactly is cvt_amino and amino&? I get how this works, but don't understand where the int is then placed.  After each line is converted to an int, I need to find if certain patterns (k-mers) are contained, and then cout how many of each pattern is found in each line.

Comment: @JerryCoffin ATCGATTGA to an int, then check how many of certain patterns occur, and then printout result, then repeat for each line.

Comment: @Chief: Not clear what you mean by "how many of certain patterns occur". Do you mean "often the sequence "ATCGATTGA " occurred in a file, or something more like "how often "AT" occurred in a single string?

Comment: @JerryCoffin to be super specific, the first number is the size of the possible patterns, and the second is how many lines below to check. If the first numbers were 3 and 2, it should check  ATCGATTGA and find that it includes ATC, TCG, CGA, ATT, TTG, and TGA.  It would then do the same for the next line, and after printout how many of each little pattern was found in each line.

Comment: @Chief: In that case, I see no advantage (at all) to converting the whole to an `int` first. Rather the contrary, it appears (to me) to add work without utility.

Comment: @Chief: Just to add one more point: I think you'd probably have gotten considerably more useful answers if you'd started by asking about what you really want to know/do (and you still could do that by asking a new question that explains the format and what you actually want to accomplish).